# SQL WHERE <from another table>

Tags: sql

Say you have these tables:

```
PHARMACY(**___id_pharmacy___**, name, addr, tel)
PHARMACIST(**___Insurance_number___**, name, surname, qualification, **id_pharmacy**)
SELLS(**___id_pharmacy___**, **___name___**, price)
DRUG(**___Name___**, chem_formula, **id_druggistshop**)
DRUGGISTSHOP(**___id_druggistshop___**, name, address)
```

I think this will be more specific.

So, I'm trying to construct an SQL statement, in which I will fetch the data from id_pharmacy and name FROM PHARMACY, the insurance_number, name, and surname columns from PHARMACIST, for all the pharmacies that sell the drug called Kronol.

And that's basically it. I know I'm missing the relationships in the code I wrote previously.

Note: Those column names which have underscores left and right to them are underlined(Primary keys).

Comment: What's the relationship between `MLIST` and `PH` and between `MLIST` and `PHCL`?

Comment: With a confusing question as this, you are better off showing us some examlpe data and the expected output

Comment: Your also attempting to UNION sets with different column counts which will fail

Comment: Ah. My mistake. Let me edit the code above. Will explain in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

The query you've written won't work in any DBMS that I know of.

You'll most likely want to use some combination of `JOINs`.

Since the exact schema isn't provided, consider this pseudo code, but hopefully it will get you on the right track.

```
SELECT PH.Ph_Number, PH.Name, PHCL.Ins_Number, PHCL.Name, PHCL.Surname
FROM   PH
  INNER JOIN PHCL ON PHCL.PH_Number = PH.Ph_Number
  INNER JOIN MLIST ON MLIST.PH_Number = PH.PH_Number
WHERE MLIST.Name = "Andy"
```

I've obviously assumed some relationships between tables that may or may not exist, but hopefully this will be pretty close.  The `UNION` operator won't work because you're selecting different columns and a different number of columns from the various tables.  This is the wrong approach all together for what you're trying to do.  It's also worth mentioning that a `LEFT JOIN` may or may not be a better option for you, depending on the exact requirements you're trying to meet.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. I edited the question in order to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, try this query:

```
SELECT  A.id_pharmacy, A.name AS PharmacyName, B.Insurance_number, 
        B.name AS PharmacistName, B.surname AS PharmacistSurname
FROM PHARMACY A
LEFT JOIN PHARMACIST B
ON A.id_pharmacy = B.id_pharmacy
WHERE A.id_pharmacy IN (SELECT id_pharmacy FROM SELLS WHERE name = 'Kronol')
```

Comment: What exactly do A. and B. mean ?

Comment: @speci, check out lines 4 & 5. The PHARMACY table has been given a short code of A and the PHARMACIST table as short code of B. To simplify the code.

Comment: @speci - As JulianKnight said, those are table aliases, so you can prefix columns by those aliases instead of the whole name of the table